# Why won't UIButtons detect a touch in a UIView on a UIActionSheet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiactionsheet

I've added a UIView (which contains the UIImageView for the background, three UIButtons which say "Test" and the final UIButton to dismiss the view called "Finished") as a subview of my UIActionSheet.

Why won't *any* of these buttons detect touches? My UIView has User Interaction Enabled checked.

I'd appreciate some help with this as I've been pulling my hair out (not literally of course)!

Here's my set up:

[image]

Comment: set action for that buttons then you can do what ever you want in that action methods

Comment: i think it's not possible, because I have already tried it, same issue came then I put a navigation bar with two button and a PickerView in action Sheet. If you want to present complete View then my suggestion is to use presentModelViewController.

Comment: I just wanted to mimic the animation of the UIActionSheet to bring up a little dialog at the bottom. I didn't really want a full sized view to show. Is there any way to still do this?

Comment: Can you post some of the code for the actions sheet and buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking mimic the UIActionSheet, I'd just create a UIVew subclass called something like "CoolActionSheet" and programatically place the buttons on there. Then, when you press the buttons it triggers a delegate method in a protocol which will be implemented in your main view controller so do something.

To show and hide the action picker use UIView animations **in the CoolActionSheet class** like so:

```
-(void)showSheet {
    NSLog(@"Showing sheet...");
    //Set the x/y position of the action sheet to JUST off-screen
    CGFloat xPos = parentView.frame.origin.x;
    CGFloat yPos = parentView.frame.size.height+kActionSheetHeight;

    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, kActionSheetWidth, kActionSheetHeight)];

    /*Here is where you would add your other UI objects such as buttons 
    and set their @selector to a method in your CoolActionSheet protocol. You could then implement this delegate method in 
    your main view controller to carry out a custom action. You might also want to add a background image to the view or something else.
    For example: */
    UIButton *coolButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonDimensions];
    [coolButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didDismissActionSheet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:coolButton];

    [self.parentView addSubview:self.view];

    //Slide the sheet up from the bottom of the screen
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^(void) {
        //Slide banner in from left to right
        [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, yPos-kActionSheetHeight, kActionSheetWidth, kActionSheetHeight)];
    }];
}
```

And to hide:

```
-(void)hideSheet {
    NSLog(@"Hiding");
    CGFloat xPos = parentView.frame.origin.x;
    CGFloat yPos = parentView.frame.size.height+kActionSheetHeight;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^(void) {
        [self setFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, 320, 65)];
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self removeFromSuperview]; //Clean up
    }];
}
```

You may also want to grey-out the parent view. Again, in the CoolActionSheet.m:

```
-(void)shadeParentView {
    UIView *shadedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(, 0, 320, 480)];

    [shadedView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    [shadedView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [shadedView setAlpha:0.0];

    [self addSubview:shadedView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [shadedView setAlpha:0.5];
    }];
```

}

You would need to set your *parentView* to the view controller's view. So, to call the action sheet in your main view controller you would:

```
CoolActionSheet *coolSheet = [[CoolActionSheet alloc] init];
[coolSheet setParentView:self.view];
[coolSheet setSheetDelegate:self]; //set the delegate to implement button press methods in this view controller
```

This might seem a bit long-winded, but it's a good MVC pattern to separate it out into another view class like this. And you now have a custom class that you can just import into any other project and it'll work!

I haven't had a chance to test out this specific code, but the whole approach is good. Points to take away from this:

- Use a custom UIView class
- Implement delegate methods to execute tasks in your main view controller when a button is pressed in your subview.
- Implement a good MVC structure to avoid spaghetti code.

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: Here is a very basic sample project:
http://cl.ly/0Z2I3w1g461h16302C0c

Hope this provides some clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.view.window];
```